# Vacancy Generation / Annihilation Time (Relaxation Time)

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, atomic-physics, equilibrium

Vacancy Generation/Annihilation Time, Recombination Time and Relaxation Time ($\tau$) are all synonymously used in atomic physics literatures. They're defined as the time that it takes for vacancies and atoms to position in steady state sites and reach a thermo-mechanical equilibrium concentration. The relaxation time for copper atoms/vacancies used in semiconductor industry is usually reported to be in order of several milliseconds. I am trying to approximate this quantity by studying the diffusion mechanism. I have made a theory (which might be completely wrong as I'm not expert in this area). Please correct me if I'm doing something wrong. Here is my theory:

**Theory:** The relaxation time seems to be highly correlated to diffusivity and the lattice geometry. Thus, the vacancy relaxation time can be approximated by the following equation:

$$\tau = D_v^{-1} \times A $$

where $D_v$ is the diffusion coefficient and $A$ is the area of the diffusion path that a single vacancy travels along while it diffuses.

**Theorem Check:** I testified this for copper at room temperature as follows:

$A \approx$ (the spacing between copper atoms) * (copper atom diameter). $A \approx 0.23 nm \times 0.256 nm = 0.2944nm^2$ (This might be very crude).

hence

$$\tau = D_v^{-1} \times A = \frac{1}{D_0}\exp(\frac{Ea}{kT}) \times A
= \frac{1}{5.2e-5[m^2/s]} \times \\\exp(\frac{0.77[eV]}{8.617e-5[eV/K] \times 298.15[K]}) \times 2.944e-20 [m^2] = 5.877 ms $$

which makes totally sense [M.E. Sarycheva, Yu.V. Zhitnikova, L. Boruckib, C.-L. Liub, T.M. Makhviladze, "A new, general model for mechanical stress evolution during electromigration", Thin Solid Films Volume 365, Issue 2, 17 April 2000, Pages 211–218].

-- I'd not be surprised if I'm wrong.